# Change an image src with the [src] binding? (Amp for Email)

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

On the amp-bind Amp for Email documentation page, it shows an example (A slightly more complex example) of binding [src] to amp-img to change an image source path:

```
<amp-state id="myAnimals">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "dog": {
        "imageUrl": "/img/dog.jpg",
        "style": "greenBackground"
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>

<!-- Or change an image's src with the [src] binding. -->
<amp-img width="300" height="200" src="/img/dog.jpg"
    [src]="myAnimals[currentAnimal].imageUrl">
</amp-img>
```

However when I validate in Playground I get:
The attribute '[src]' may not appear in tag 'AMP-IMG (AMP4EMAIL)'.

I'm trying to do something similar with the Carousel component (type="slides"), where as i click to the next/prev slide I want copy/image located elsewhere in the email to change. While I can get the copy to change, it doesn't seem I can do the same for the image.

Is it not possible to change an image source path using the amp-bind component for Amp for Email?? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Vadim, you can use templating via amp-mustache to modify the src attribute of an amp-img. e.g.

```
<amp-list ...>
...
 <template type="amp-mustache">
    <div class="products">
        <amp-img width="150"
               height="100"
               alt="{{name}}"
               src="{{img}}"></amp-img>
        <p class="name">{{name}}</p>
        <p class="star">{{{stars}}}</p>
        <p class="price">{{price}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

...

I can't recall the design decisions behind why binding on src isn't possible though security seems to be likely answer. So unfortunately if you noticed templating is only applicable when nested within an amp-form or amp-list component. If there is a compelling enough use case to allow support for it outside of those components then feel free to create a request for a feature and we will be more than happy to work with you on defining the requirements and implementing the changes. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I'm a newbie when it comes to AMP. Right now in my html I have 1)Jason script 2)amp-carousel 3)content section that will update. Based on your response it seems I need to include the amp-list component which will include a src path to the json script (instead of embed in html). Do I replace the content section below with the amp-list ?
    <div class="center">
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/inline-examples/images/image1.jpg" 
     width="175"
     height="150"
     [src]="myState.adventure[currentAdventure].image"></amp-img>
    </div>